# Snowflake, SQL where clause

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to write query with where clause:

```
where       
    pl.ods_site_id in (select id from table1 where ...)
```

But if subquery (table1) didn't return anything, where clause doesn't need to include in result query (like it returns TRUE).

How can I do it? (I have snowflake SQL dialect)

Answer (score 1):

You could include a second condition:

```
where pl.ods_site_id in (select id from table1 where ...) or
      not exists (select id from table1 where ...)
```

This explicitly checks for the subquery returning no rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a `join` instead, Snowflake supports `qualify` clause which might come in handy here. You can run this on Snowflake to see how it works.

```
with 
pl (ods_site_id) as  (select 1 union all select 5),

table1 (id) as (select 5) --change this to 7 to test if it returns ALL on no match

select a.*
from pl a
left join table1 b on a.ods_site_id = b.id -- and other conditions you want to add
qualify b.id = a.ods_site_id --either match the join condition
        or count(b.id) over () = 0; --or make sure there is 0 match from table1
```